# The bash script using do while loop is executing infinitely

Tags: bash, shell-script

Below is the bash script. Its executing infinitely. I want to execute the script only for 10 servers, which i have stored in servers.txt file. please help

```
#!/bin/bash
user=$1
pass=$2

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ];then
echo "Please run the script with userid and password as arguments"
fi

cat servers.txt | while read host

do {

 ./sandy_try.sh $user $host $pass


} < /dev/null; done
```

Comment: Question 1 in [the Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)...

Comment: While you could use input redirection instead of the cat, I can't see how that will result in an endless loop...

Comment: Hi @ilkkachu : I have nine servers in servers.txt and after iterating to the 9 servers again it is starting from the first server. I have made a below comment on@pfnusel answer. please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like

```
while read line; do
    echo do something fancy with "$line"
done < servers.txt
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash
user=$1
pass=$2

 while read host; do

        ./sandy_try.sh $user $host $pass
       
done < servers.txt

Comment: @sandeep Is it working now or not?